# Ember's HTMLBars Compiler Error: Unexpected token export

Tags: ember.js, broccolijs

I've inherited an Ember application at v1.8.1. I have successfully upgraded the application to v.1.9.1, and would like to continue to update it to at least v1.13.8.

In my v1.10.1 build, it appears that the `ember-template-compiler` is not quite meshing with Ember and am getting the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The line erroring for the 'name' error is:

```
set(appController, 'currentRouteName', infos[infos.length - 1].name);
```

`infos` is empty... so it doesn't have an object to call `name` on.

---

I'm looking for some direction in how to better track down the error, and what needs to be done to successfully upgrade.

The project is using broccoli (but not ember cli), so i'm trying to make the `ember-cli-htmlbars` plugin work.

Is there a better way to compile HTMLBars for Ember v1.10.1?

Should I transition the project over to Ember cli?

Please let me know what code you need would need to see.

Comment: Transitioning to Ember CLI should yield better results.

Comment: You should definitely transition to Ember CLI. You'll basically be reproducing it trying to fix this problem.

Comment: @pichfl - Thanks pichfl and locks, I'll start looking into transitioning to Ember CLI. Is there a particularly useful guide you know of that will help the progress?

Comment: Can you tell us which version of `ember-cli-htmlbars` are you using? Keep in mind this note: 

`If you are using ember-cli-htmlbars with a 1.9.x project please continue to use ember-cli-htmlbars@0.6.x.`

So maybe you're using 0.6.x which may not be compatible with Ember 1.10.x. If that's a case try updating this plugin.
PS. ember-cli is always good choice. It takes care about building process.

Comment: @aero depending on your project structure it should be rather easy. 1. Install ember-cli. 2. Create a new project 3. Copy over your app directory 4. Run project, install missing dependencies as required (following the error messages). Done.

Comment: @pichfl - Thanks Pichfl. Creating a new project with ember-cli and bring the old project into the new one is a clever idea. Thank you!

Comment: @KarolŁuckiewicz Thanks Karol, I'm using ember-cli-htmlbars v1.1.1.